# How Can i set Collcetion view 1 Row Display 3 image layout

Tags: ios, iphone

[image: i want to display 3 images in collection view 1 row, please see attachment image, how can i get it done ?]

i want to display 3 images in collection view 1 row, please see attachment image, how can i get it done ?

Comment: Hi! It would probably be helpful if you could describe what you've already tried/searched the internet for and give more detail on the problem at hand, so that others find it easier to answer your question. Feel free to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Create Class `exampleclassname` , subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

After in implementation file write below code.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGSize)itemSize
{
    NSInteger numberOfColumns = 3;

   CGFloat itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns;

    itemWidth = itemWidth - 10;
    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
}
```

And after in your class where you are using `UiCollectionView` Just import `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and in `viewdidLoad` method write below 1 line code:

```
 self.MyOfferCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[CustomImageFlowLayout alloc] init];
```